# Automate an html slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript to run an image slideshow on my webpage, I adapted the script from .......... The script works ok but I have to start it manually. I would appreciate if someone can give me a line of code so that the script can start automatically once the brouser loads. I give below the whole code, including the hte html which contains it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var num=1
img1 = new Image ()
img1.src = "img1.jpg"
img2 = new Image ()
img2.src = "img2.jpg"
img3 = new Image ()
img3.src = "img3.jpg"
img4 = new Image ()
img4.src = "img4.jpg"

text1 = "Text for Picture One"
text2 = "Text for Picture two"
text3 = "Text for Picture Three"
text4 = "Text for Picture Four"

function slideshowUp()
{
 num=num+1
 if (num==5)
  {num=1}
  document.mypic.src=eval("img"+num+".src")
  document.myform.mytext.value=eval("text"+num)
}
function slideshowBack()
{
  num=num-1
  if (num==0)
  {num=4}
  document.mypic.src=eval("img"+num+".src")
  document.myform.mytext.value=eval("text"+num)
}
</SCRIPT>  
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<IMG SRC="img1.jpg" NAME="mypic" BORDER=0 WIDTH="400">
<p>
<FORM NAME="myform">
<INPUT TYPE="text" width="100" NAME="mytext" VALUE="Text For Picture One">
</FORM>
<A HREF="JavaScript:slideshowBack()"> Previous Image</A>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<A HREF="JavaScript:slideshowUp()"> Next Image</A>

<NOSCRIPT>
<!--
for search engines and non-javascript browsers
-->
</NOSCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Excuse me I did not give credit to the author of the script> It is from Joe Burns:http://www.htmlgoodies.com/feedback.php/http:/www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471341/So-You-Want-A-SlideShow-Huh.htm

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole script with:

```
$(function() {
    // your scripts go here

    slideshowUp();   // add these two lines
    slideshowBack();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Dubrava. I will try this code. At first trial it does not work, but it gives me something to work with and I will keep trying and see

Comment: Ok i see what you mean @Dubrava. In fact I already do have the two lines slideshowUp(); slideshowBack(), except that they are links and currently the script does not have a start. I can only move through the images one by one by pressing next or previous, facilitated by the two lines above.

Comment: Fortunately i was able to get a working example from here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/